# Can scripts with async attribute trigger callback functions when loaded?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Google Pagespeed told me to load my JS files asynchronously, so I wrote this code:

```
// Add script elements as a children of the body
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var filesToLoad = [
        ["/assets/plugins/typeahead.bundle.min.js", "onTypeaheadLoaded"],
        ["https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=googlePlusOnloadCallback", ""]
    ];

    filesToLoad.forEach(function(entry) {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = entry[0];
        if (entry[1] != "") { // if an onload callback is present (NOTE: DOES NOT SUPPORT NAMESPACES -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/359910/1101095)
            element.onload = function() {
                if (typeof window[entry[1]] != "undefined") {
                    window[entry[1]]();
                }
            };
        }
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    });
}

// Check for browser support of event handling capability
if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
```

However, someone just directed me to [this article](https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/), which says using the `async` attribute is better than injecting script tags (this is contrary to what I've read most places, but the author show evidence he's right).

So, my question is, if I change to using the `async` attribute, is there a way to have a function triggered when the script is done loading?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you can still use your method, but set the `async` property on `element` to be `true`, and achieve the best of both worlds. Remember, if you need scripts to execute in a specific order (like making sure jQuery is loaded before a plugin), you can't use something like `async`. Also, just a suggestion - you might want to set the `src` property **after** the `onload` property in case the file is cached and the browser immediately executes the `onload` that you wouldn't already have set.

Comment: @Ian I'm not sure.. Someone asked that question in the article I linked to and the author said `It's a noop. If your inline script is below CSS then you'll block on CSSOM before you can execute it. if you move the inline block above CSS than it's equivalent to <script async="">.`